# Why can define the electric potential (voltage) in alternating current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current, voltage

(All SI unit used in this question)

The electric potential U is defined in electrostatic field that [image] The electric field is the (negative) gradient of some scaler verctor, if and only if the electirc field is conservative, namely [image],Or the Integral of the electric field is $0$ when the path is closed. This is only ture when [image],as a consequence of the Faraday's Law. But in alternating current, the current changes, which means the **disturbution** of the charge varies. This means the integral of a closed path(or curl) of the electric field is definitely non-zero . So can we even define the concept of Electric Potential (The difference of potential is the alternating voltage which is used everywhere in the analysis of alternating current) here? Does that means there is a criterion that the curl of the electric field is approximately $0$ (May be when the frequency is low or because the simple harmonic sine wave “cancel” in a long period)? Thanks for giving a explanation on this.

Comment: Not quite true that the e field has to be conservative or almost conservative. When you will get to study transmission lines and waveguides you will learn that the voltage between two points of the same cross section defined as the line integral of the E field for TEM modes is a very useful *measurable* quantity despite the fact that EM waves maybe propagating left and right, up and down with the fields may be varying at terahertz rates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when textbooks treat AC circuits without using the full apparatus of Maxwell's equations which take into account all of the electrodynamical aspects of circuits, they are assuming that the fields are such that they *vary slowly*. For a field that is varying slowly,
$${\partial\vec B\over\partial t}=0,$$
therefore Faraday's law implies that electrostatic conditions apply, i.e. $\nabla\times\vec E=0$.
It is reasonable to ask one's self: is 60Hz really slowly varying? Well, given that the electric potentials satisfy the wave equation, then yes. Electromagnetic waves travel at the speed of light: $1/\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}$, thus changes in the circuit are equalized so rapidly that violations slowly varying assumption only become important at much larger frequencies.

Comment: Thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

In AC circuits, we intentionally concentrate the induction in "inductors" and "transformers". We aspire to be able to consider the electric field outside them as essentially static, and model them as "black boxes" that produce that static field without having to worry too much about the dynamic details inside.

It works fine in textbooks, and often works on the bench, but we sometimes have to deal with "parasitic" induction occurring outside the places we wish to confine it to. Take an oscilloscope, connect it to a loop of wire, and in a typical lab setting you'll see millivolts of induction.

Comment: Thank you for answering